# Codility MissingInteger task, one case timeout

Tags: java, stream

The task is to found first positive integer which is not present in a given array.

I already found the correct solution, however I don't understand why my solution has a good time for "large" input and bad for "medium".

Here is my solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Solution 
{
    public int solution(int[] A) 
    {        
        int[] a = IntStream.of(A).distinct().filter( s -> s > 0 ).toArray();
        Arrays.sort(a);
        int next = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
        {
            if( a[i] == next )
                next++;
            else if ( a[i] > next)
                break;
        }

        return next;
    }
}
```

And the link to the result:
https://codility.com/demo/results/demo8F8DDW-9BK/

Comment: I think your implementation could benefit from sorting the IntStream prior to the `distinct` call. (`int[] a = IntStream.of(A).sorted().distinct().filter( s -> s > 0 ).toArray();`). Or it might run faster without using Streams at all, since you are iterating over the array twice - first time to produce an array of distinct positive values and second time to find the minimum value not present.

Comment: I worked out! Could you explain why is it better now? On the other hand now i have different tests... The one which printed "1.5 s expected" now accepts over 2s.

Comment: Finding the distinct elements of an array is much easier if the array is already sorted, and since you are sorting the array anyway, you might as well do it prior to `distinct`.

Comment: Ok, but notice that later I sort lesser or equal array because I get rid of identical and negative numbers. So sorted array might ( but dont have to ) be much smaller than initial. So how do you know that sorting -> distinct will be better than distinct -> sorting shorter array.

Answer (score 3):

The problem specification says expected worst-case time complexity is O(N), so you can't sort the data. Sorting it is O(N log N). If your sorting solution got accepted anyway, apparently their test isn't strict enough, or their biggest test case isn't constructed properly.

Fortunately, you don't have to sort the data. You already know up front the solution is at most the length of the input array, so only numbers between 1 and `input.length` are interesting. You have enough memory to keep a boolean for all of them (You already store that many integers anyway)

```
public int solution (int[] input) {                                         
    boolean[] isPresent = new boolean[input.length + 1];                    
    for (int i : input) {                                                   
        if (0 < i && i < isPresent.length) {                                         
            isPresent[i] = true;                                            
        }                                                                   
    }                                                                       
    for (int i = 1; i < isPresent.length; i++) {                            
        if (!isPresent[i]) return i;                                        
    }                                                                       
    return input.length + 1;                                                
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned before I know the "correct" solution, but thanks for pointing that the sorting is inappriopriate. Point for you.